# ASP.NET AJAX Gauges with Asynchronous Update and animation

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gauge

I´m currently working on a dashboard styled project, where i need to have gauges to display current values.

can someone point me to some commercial or open source asp.net ajax controls that include gauges with these capabilities?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress has a suite of controls for ASP.NET which include gauges. [ASPxGauges Demos](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGaugesDemos/)

I've recently used these in a project to display current information by doing asynch postbacks on timer tick, using their CallBackPanel (thier equivlent to an UpdatePanel).

Overall, the learning curve was not to steep. I would definitely recommend reading the documentation [ASPxGauges Docs](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5230) before jumping in. Design time support is available to create the controls, but is very tedious nonetheless.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Rich, thanks for the reply! 

What exactly do you mean by "Design time support is available to create the controls, but is very tedious nonetheless."? Do you mean it´s difficult to utilize the DevExpress Controls?

I´ve also foun another provider, at www.componentart.com 

Have you heard about them?

Comment: @SlickD There is a designer you can use to create controls with default settings (pretty easy).  However, it can become tedious when want to customize the controls. Customization is done using a property style gui which requires you to use a context menu (right click) on each component to set the properties. Unfortunately, its not easy to do this in markup cause you don't really know what properties to set.  Haven't used ComponentArt tools; however, the main difference I see is the CA's Client-side API; IMO would be very useful for user interaction.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer Rich! I´ll take a closer look into DevExpress and compare to the others I´ve found!

Answer (score 1):

You may also use Telerik gauge component for ASP.net AJAX.

Comment: They have that now? Last time I checked they only had it for silverlight...I'll check it out! Thanks!

Comment: Yes now! Actually they have added it since Telerik's ASP.net AJAX 2012 Q3 collection.